# Проблема с маской для input-а (JQuery plugin) на Android-е

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Поставил плагин для маски `input-ов` - [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)

Задал маску нужному мне полю. Но нашел маленькую неприятность. Она оказалось на Android-е, на ПК всё работает. Суть в том что когда набираешь на андроиде курсор не перемещается после введенного символа как на ПК, и получается так что при маске `(000) 000 00 00` при вводе получается такое:

Должно быть: `(056) 123 45 67`.
Получается: `(765) 0--`. Цифры вообще пропадают.

Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/135 ?

Comment: @Visman сработало. спасибо.